# In AngularJS, how can I get to the next image in a json array with the keyboard arrows?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS to navigate through photos in a JSON array. I'd like to be able to navigate with my keyboard arrows (<-- and -->) to flip through the photos. How can I do this?

I'm still learning AngularJS, so if there's a "right way" to do something like this, now is the time to learn!

```
 <div id="main" data-ng-controller="MediaController">
     <div class="image-holder">
          <img class="photo" data-ng-src="{{ media_list.cur.m2_url }}" height="{{ media_list.cur.m2_height }}" width="{{ media_list.cur.m2_width }}" alt="{{ media_info.title }}">
      </div>
      <div class="tools-on-hover">
          <span ng-if="media_list.bck.title_url"><a href="{{ media_list.bck.title_url }}" class="btn-prev">prev</a></span>
          <span ng-if="media_list.fwd.title_url"><a href="{{ media_list.fwd.title_url }}" class="btn-next">next</a></span>
      </div>
  </div>

media_list.bck is the previous image (returns false if it doesn't exist)
media_list.fwd is the next image (returns false if it doesn't exist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple setup that might help you capture the clicks and use them in a controller:

First we will create a directive that will capture the keypresses.  Please note you could encapsulate the entire codeset for your image gallery inside a directive if you wanted, but for this example this is simpler.  We will broadcast a simple string out to the app as 'left' or 'right';

```
app.directive('keys', function($rootScope) {
  return function(scope, element, attr) {
    $("body").keydown(function(e) {
      console.log(e);
      if (e.keyCode == 37) { // left
        $rootScope.$broadcast('keypress', 'left');
      } else if (e.keyCode == 39) { // right
        $rootScope.$broadcast('keypress', 'right');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

In our controller we will receive this event and you'd obviously be cycling through some array of images here and would set the index forward or backwards.  In this example I'm just putting the event value in a scope variable.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.pressed = 'none';

  $scope.$on('keypress', function(event, val) {
    $scope.pressed = val;
    $scope.$apply();
  })
});
```

Demo:  http://plnkr.co/edit/4sJ0fHbTQNJP1gxZZClO?p=preview

Here is a little more functional controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.pressed = 'none';

  $scope.images = ['http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff','http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff', 'http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff'];

  $scope.selected = 0;

  $scope.$on('keypress', function(event, val) {
    $scope.pressed = val;
    if (val=='right') {
       $scope.selected = $scope.selected + 1;
    } else {
      $scope.selected = $scope.selected - 1;
    }
    $scope.$apply();
  })
});
```

Demo:  http://plnkr.co/edit/x298lAJtetIm8chAENZf?p=preview